# numbers in a list greater than the average

Tags: list, recursion, racket

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong. I need to write a program that filters the numbers below the average of a list of numbers and only keeps the numbers that are greater than the average of all the numbers.

```
(define (total lon)
(cond
[(empty? lon) 0]
[else (+ first lon) (total (rest lon)))]))


(define (mean alon)
(/ (total alon) (length alon)))

(define (average-filter log)
  (cond
    [(empty? log) empty]
    [(> (first log) (mean log))
     (cons (first log) (average-filter (rest log)))]
    [else (average-filter (rest log))]))
```

I expect it to remove all the ones below average, but I end up with an empty list.

Ex
(average-filter (list 1 2 3)) -> empty
when i should be getting:
(cons 3 empty)

Answer (score 3):

Since `log` shrinks on each recursive call `(mean log)` changes too!

Compute the mean once:

```
(define (average-filter log)
  (average-filter-h log (mean log)))
```

And then filter the numbers that are greater:

```
(define (average-filter-h log mean)
  (cond
    [(empty? log) empty]
    [(> (first log) mean)
     (cons (first log) (average-filter-h (rest log) mean))]
    [else (average-filter-h (rest log) mean)]))
```

*side note*:

You can also use abstractions to put this more succinctly:

```
(define (mean alon)
  (/ (apply + alon) (length alon)))

(define (average-filter log)
  (let ([m (mean log)])
    (filter (λ (x) (> x m)) log)))
```